# Replace Content using MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

In many of my column I have some data like this :

"Some Data. [content]Some Content[/content] Another Data"

I want to remove the substring which starts with [content] and ends with [/content]. The result should be :

"Some Data. Another Data"

I know it is possible by using MySQL replace() with Reg Ex but I don't how to use it.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

first get all the `string between` that string and after that you can able to replace it:

`SELECT substring_index(substring_index(field, 'content', -1), '/content', 1) FROM table_name`

after run this query, you get `between string of [content] and [/content]`

after that you just have to `update one bye one` using `foreach loop` with use of this `query`

`UPDATE table_name SET field = REPLACE(field, 'content', 'content-that-will-replace-it') WHERE INSTR(field, 'content') > 0`

Comment: I do not want to replace it only with the "content" part. I want to replace it with the "[content]Some Content[/content]".

Comment: @Thanks for your quick response. Please can you provide me the whole query with the data I have given as I am not getting it ?

Comment: I not only wants string between the content tags but with the content tags.